# Limiting string length in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have node set with header, leading, body text etc... I want to make an excerpt and show only the first 70 characters of the leading. Is there a way to do this in XSLT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath 1.0

```
substring($nodeset[self::leading],1,70)
```